# Play online without HoTS expansion?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have Starcraft 2 WoL. I would like to play online (matchmaking) but the button are disabled.

Does this mean I can't play online with only WoL?

Comment: I don't know why the buttons are disabled however from what I can tell you should still be able to play WoL online without HoTS - what do the tool-tips for the disabled buttons say?

Comment: Maybe becusse the game its still downloading all the stuff.. I will wait the others 3GB

Comment: check in your settings if HoTS is selected, in HoTS, I have a popup that says I can switch between versions of the game in the options.

Comment: @HugoTrudel: you were right, if you want make an answer

Comment: @Justin the disable buttons doesn't say anything but after you log in to your account it says to upgrade to get full version of starcraft to unlock those Macthmaking Versus A.I and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in your settings if HoTS is selected, in HoTS, I have a popup that says I can switch between versions of the game in the options.

Answer (score 3):

Also be aware that Blizzard [enabled "spawning" a while ago](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/10145834), which will automatically bring all players up to the highest level of anyone in their party. So if you play in a group with someone who has HoTS, you will have access to the HoTS ladder and units.